# How can I register a custom "Text Pattern" (WP 4.3) for TinyMCE?

Tags: editor, visual-editor

WP 4.3 added some really cool editor features: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/08/01/editor-enhancements-in-4-3-%E2%9C%A8/

The "Text Patterns" are really useful to create lists, quotes and headings, but I'd like to have other shortcuts for my specific needs.

There should be an API for it, but I didn't (immediately) find it so figured I would make sure there's an answer here :)

Some specific custom shortcuts I want:

- `$` for `<code>`
- `%` for `<blockquote class='translation'>`

### Tragedy strikes!

This trac ticket implies it's not currently possible to add new text patterns, and the feature hasn't been discussed yet.

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33300

Please prove me wrong!